# How do you set autosizing to flex in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have an iPhone project that I started as a Windows-based app and another View-based app. The  Window app has a view which I added and I want to make the view fit within the window. In the View app the view is set to stretch.

Here is what it looks like when it is off.

[image]
<sub>(source: [smallsharptools.com](http://www.smallsharptools.com/downloads/Stackoverflow/autosizing-off.png))</sub>

And here is when it is on.

http://www.smallsharptools.com/downloads/Stackoverflow/autosizing-on.png

I want to click in the middle of the Autosizing box but it does not do anything. What do I have to do in Interface Builder to make the View in a NIB to flex/stretch the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when a view is locked down like that, it means that you have some simulated UI elements in place (like a fake nav bar, tab bar, or status bar).  Select the top level view and go to the first tab of the inspector to see if any of those are turned on (you'd also see them on the view of course).

When they are all gone then you can change any of the resizing handles you like.

Answer (score 1):

The view that is provided by default has this kind of limitation but you can overcome this by adding another view (you should delete the first view) to your xib and making this view the view of your file's owner. Besides this you would also have to change the height of this new view to 480 pxls.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup